# Azure Data Lake: how to add users permissions after successful deployment with ARM and PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure, deployment, azure-resource-manager, azure-data-lake

I deploy an Azure Datalake Store and Analytics Account via ARM and PowerShell. How can I add the permissions for certain users that exist in Azure Active Directory with their email addresses after successful deployment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a parameter to keep the emails addresses

```
Param (
[string[]] $permissionsADLSUsers = @('xxx@xxx.de', 'xxx@xxx.de')
)
```

Execute the deployment and get the output from it. The output of the ARM deployment can be defined in the ARM template

```
$deploymentOutput = New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name ((Get-ChildItem $TemplateFile).BaseName + '-' + ((Get-Date).ToUniversalTime()).ToString('MMdd-HHmm')) `
                                       -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName `
                                       -TemplateFile $TemplateFile `
                                       -TemplateParameterFile $TemplateParametersFile `
                                       @OptionalParameters `
                                       -Force -Verbose `
                                       -ErrorVariable ErrorMessages
```

Add the permissions of each user defined in the parameter (in this case for the root and giving them all permissions)

```
$adlsAccountName = (Get-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $deploymentOutput.DeploymentName).Outputs.adlsName.value
foreach ($user in $permissionsADLSUsers) {
    Set-AzureRmDataLakeStoreItemAclEntry -AccountName $adlsAccountName -Path '/' -AceType User -Id (Get-AzureRmADUser -Mail $user).Id -Permissions All -Default
}
```

Check the current permissions

```
Get-AzureRmDataLakeStoreItemAclEntry -AccountName $adlsAccountName -Path '/'
```